# Readability using matrix input

Tags: r, matrix, plotly, readability

I realised that matrices are a lot faster for storing numeric data than any other format in R. Interestingly they can also be used to speed up my `plotly` code. Which is desirable because recalculating `plotly`-plots e.g. in a shiny app can be slow.

However readability in plotly suffers *a lot*. If I want a line plot together with some text and maybe some dots, the code looks like this:

```
### Creating sample data
mysim=cbind(x=rep(1:4,4),y=round(runif(16)*10,1),id=rep(1:4,each=4))

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=mysim[mysim[,'id']==1,'x'],y=mysim[mysim[,'id']==1,'y'],
            type='scatter',mode='lines',opacity=0.9,hoverinfo='skip',
            line=list(color='#AAAAAA',dash='dashed')) %>%
  add_trace(x=mysim[mysim[,'id']==2,'x'],y=mysim[mysim[,'id']==2,'y'],
            type='scatter',mode='text',
            hoverinfo='y',text=mysim[mysim[,'id']==2,'y']) %>%
  add_trace(x=mysim[mysim[,'id']==3,'x'],y=mysim[mysim[,'id']==3,'y'],
            type='scatter',mode='lines',
            line=list(color='#17becf',dash='solid'),hoverinfo='x') %>%
  add_trace(x=mysim[mysim[,'id']==4,'x'],y=mysim[mysim[,'id']==4,'y'],
            type='scatter',mode='marker')
```

That doesn't look very nice, right?

**Is there any way to make this code more readable without making it slower?** Since coding these kind of `plotly` graphs seems cumbersome to me (even when using `data.frames`), I am thinking about submitting that to Github as an open issue. Thus I want to be sure that I didn't miss something.

I tried improving readability it by

- using the `split` argument inside the `plot_ly`-wrapper (just plots every trace four times)
- using `data=mysim[mysim[,'id']==1,]` and `x=~x`or `x=~'x'` in the `add_trace` (returns an error)

Comment: You don't use the matrix format of `mysim` in the plotly code. You're just extracting some vectors from `mysim`. You could do `x1 <- mysim[mysim[,'id']==1,'x']`, etc, and use `x1`, `y1`, etc, in the plotly code.

Comment: Good angle. I didn't think of that. Still seems like an inefficient step given that for all the `add_trace`-functions in this example you need the same `x` and `y` inputs. But I understand that I end up with a speed vs readability trade-off here.